# Callback webhooks are not set when creating proxy service for twilio masked calls

Tags: service, twilio, call

I am able to create a proxy service using the PHP API using: `$twilio->proxy->v1->services->create()`. This call is creating the service with the given unique name, but ignores the other parameters such as `defaultTtl`, and callback parameters, I do not see that these parameters are set on the console.

I tried the following code below:

```
  $service = $twilio->proxy->v1->services->create(array(
    "uniqueName" => "proxy_".date("m-d-Y h:i",time()),
    "defaultTtl" => "1234",
    "callbackUrl" => "https://x.com/twilio/log/hook.html?type=normal",
    "interceptCallbackUrl" => "https://x.com/twilio/log/hook.html?type=intercept",
    "outOfSessionCallbackUrl" => "https://x.com/twilio/log/hook.html?type=other"
    ));
```

Is this a beta code restriction? What am I doing wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[`create` takes two arguments](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/5.37.0/class-Twilio.Rest.Proxy.V1.ServiceList.html#_create), the `uniqueName` and an array of other options. So your code should look like:

```php
$service = $twilio->proxy->v1->services->create(
  "proxy_".date("m-d-Y h:i",time()),
  array(
    "defaultTtl" => "1234",
    "callbackUrl" => "https://x.com/twilio/log/hook.html?type=normal",
    "interceptCallbackUrl" => "https://x.com/twilio/log/hook.html?type=intercept",
    "outOfSessionCallbackUrl" => "https://x.com/twilio/log/hook.html?type=other"
  )
);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the uniqueName is supposed to be the first parameter. The create function expect the other options as a second parameter. So this works:

```
$service = $twilio->proxy->v1->services->create(array(
  "uniqueName" => "proxy_".date("m-d-Y h:i",time()),
  "defaultTtl" => "1234",
  "callbackUrl" => "https://x.com/twilio/log/hook.html?type=normal",
  "interceptCallbackUrl" => "https://x.com/twilio/log/hook.html? 
type=intercept",
"outOfSessionCallbackUrl" => "https://x.com/twilio/log/hook.html?type=other"
));
```

The API document for service->create() is not at an easy place to find.